# Stack Dump in Rspec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm just running a simple test.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Show Movie' do 
    it 'shows single movie' do 

        movie = Movie.create(movie_attributes(total_gross: 20000000))

        visit movie_url(movie)

        expect(page).to have_text(movie.title)
        expect(page).to have_textmovie.rating()
        expect(page).to have_text("$20,000,000.00")

    end
end
```

But the test is all, well, i don't have a clue whats going on in there, heres how the test returns.

```
Last login: Sat Jul 12 16:17:19 on ttys000
Spencers-MacBook-Pro:skeleton_app spencerlong$ rspec spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb
/Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:5: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:9:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/version.rb:5:in `require'
/Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:73: warning: method redefined; discarding old children=
/Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:197: warning: literal in condition
/Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:8: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:7:in `<module:Script>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:9:in `<class:Literal>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:9:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/number.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/number.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/color.rb:1: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:7:in `<module:Script>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:10:in `<class:Literal>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:10:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/color.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/color.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/bool.rb:1: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/features/show_movie_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/skeleton_app/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/gems/bundler-1.6.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_functions.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass.rb:93:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/engine.rb:40:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/operation.rb:2:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/string.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:7:in `<module:Script>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:11:in `<class:Literal>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb:11:in `require'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/bool.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/bool.rb:1:in `require'
/Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/null.rb:1: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/sass-3.2.19/lib/sass/script/literal.rb
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/spencerlong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load'
    from /Users/spencerlong/Desktop/Rails Toolbox/
```

Looks like a stack dump to me, I would just like to test my code as it was running before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have enabled the `--warnings` (`-w`) option of RSpec.

Remove the option from your `.rspec` file and those warnings should disappear.